# 'IEnumerable< >' does not contain a definition for ' ' and no extension method ' ' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable< >

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Full error

> 'IEnumerable<UploadFileData>' does not contain a definition for
>   'InvoiceDate' and no extension method 'InvoiceDate' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'IEnumerable<UploadFileData>' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm currently trying to figure out why I get this error. I have my model specified as IEnumerable, and I'm looping my list. Any help would be appreciated.

The final outcome after this is fixed should be that I can upload a file, and it will search the 2nd element in the array for an invoice date that is not a supported format. Then it will output the validationMessage next to the invoice #.

View

```
@using UploadData.Models
@model IEnumerable<UploadFileData>
<html>
<body>
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Index", "ValidateUpload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="validateFile" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="Submit" />
}
@if (Model.Count() > 0)
{
    <hr />
    <table id="counttable">
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="1">Invoice #</th>
            <th rowspan="1">Error</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (UploadFileData ValidationOutput in Model)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>@ValidationOutput.Invoice</td>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.InvoiceDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
</body>
</html>
```

Model

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;

namespace UploadData.Models
{
public class UploadFileData : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required]
    public string Invoice { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string InvoiceDate { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        DateTime date;
        var property = new[] { "InvoiceDate" };
        string[] formats = {"MM/d/yyyy", "M/dd/yyyy"};
        if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(InvoiceDate, formats, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Invalid date format. Dates should be M/d/yyyy OR MM/d/yyyy", property);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Controller

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UploadData.Models;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{

public class ValidateUploadController : Controller
{
    // GET: ValidateUpload
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new List<UploadFileData>());
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase validateFile)
    {
        List<UploadFileData> ValidateOutput = new List<UploadFileData>();
        if (validateFile != null)
        {
            string idate = string.Empty;
            string invoice = string.Empty;
            int namecount = 1;
            string dir = Server.MapPath("~/sourcefiles/");
            string strbuild = string.Empty;
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(validateFile.FileName);
            string fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(validateFile.FileName);
            string newFullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/textfiles"), fileName);

            while (System.IO.File.Exists(newFullPath))
            {
                string tempFileName = string.Format("{0}({1})", fileNameOnly, namecount++);
                newFullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/textfiles"), tempFileName + Path.GetExtension(fileName));
            }
            validateFile.SaveAs(newFullPath);
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(newFullPath))
            {
                while ((strbuild = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] strArray = strbuild.Split('|');

                    if (strArray[0] == "1")
                    {
                        invoice = strArray[1];
                        idate = strArray[2];

                        ValidateOutput.Add(new UploadFileData
                        {
                            Invoice = invoice,
                            InvoiceDate = idate,
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return View(ValidateOutput);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Shouldn’t you be sending an IEnumerable<T> instead of a List<T> in your View?

Comment: That's what I don't really understand. I think I should be sending a List because that's how my controller is setup to parse the data, but when I remove IEnumerable from the model, I cannot use the foreach loop that I need to read over the list. Should I be using something else?

Comment: Using IEnumerable<T> in your view and passing a List<T> from your controller will work fine. That shouldn't cause any issues.

Comment: Ar what point are you given this error?

Comment: @Xiodrade Your razor view model is type `IEnumerable<UploadFileData>` so when you try to use `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.InvoiceDate` here "m" references the view model which is of type IEnumerable and since there is no property `InvoiceDate` on IEnumerable<UploadFileData> it is causing error

Comment: FYI you can use &lt; and &gt; instead of < and > in questions

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I sort of understand what you are saying, but I'm not sure how to fix the issue since without IEnumerable in my view I can't run my foreach loop. I'm fairly new with this, so any examples or references would be appreciated

Comment: @Xiodrade I suggest you create a partial view for rendering each table row and pass each `UploadFileData` object as a model to that partial view. The view model of that partial view should be of type `UploadData` and then you can apply validation on each object using `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` http://dotnetmentors.com/mvc/render-partialview-with-model.aspx

Comment: You can use `List<T>` in your View!

Comment: @DavideVitali the error occurs before running my build in my solution error list. Mohisin - I essentially do this already. It's not partially rendering because I specify a shared layout that I omitted out of the original post. I understand what you're saying, but my level knowledge isn't high enough to factor all that in with uploading a file and adding validation. I'm currently just trying to fix what I have before optimizing and rebuilding my solution

Comment: It’s maybe not that proper, but you could use ValidationOutput instead of m.

Comment: @Nikolaus I was actually doing this earlier, and while it does remove the error it doesn't actually pull my validation from my model, so it loops my list and outputs all of them on the table instead of only the ones with the validation error.

Comment: Then I suggest to try Mohsin Mehmood‘s hint.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. Here:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.InvoiceDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

as Mohsin Mehmood suggested, `m` is of `IEnumerable<UpdloadFileData>`, which has no `InvoiceDate` property. You are trying to get a property of a single elements but referring to its "container" (IEnumerable). What you need to do is

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Where(x => x.InvoiceDate == ValidationOutput.InvoiceDate), "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Comment: You have an extra bracket after .InvoiceDate by the way. Thanks for the assistance - one step closer to resolving this. I am now getting the error System.InvalidOperationException: 'Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.' after I attempt to upload a file.

Comment: You don’t need the [Required] attribute as you’re inheriting from IValidatableObject. Might be this....

Comment: Removing the required did not resolve it unfortantly